# Do @ref's in Blazor have to be nullable to avoid warnings if nullable reference types are turned on?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

If I have nullable reference types turned on, what is the best practice to avoid a warning when using an @ref reference in Blazor?

Example:
`<Modal @ref="addModal"></Model>`

`private Modal addModal;`

Will produce:
`CS8618 Non-nullable field 'addModal' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the field as nullable.`

AND

`CS8625 Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.`

If I try to initialize it, like this:
`private Modal addModal = new Modal()`
I still get:
`CS8625 Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.`

I can make the reference nullable, like this:

`private Modal? addModal;`

But then I need to do null checks every time its used to avoid warnings, even though it can't actually ever be null.

Comment: In my personal opinion, the nature of the Blazor architecture makes NRT super annoying to adhere to since so many conventions are late-bound and prevent proper NRT semantics.  i.e. this exact point around `ref` fields.  The best workaround I'm aware of is to initialize the field to `default!`; (this is known as "[null forgiveness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving)") and do your best to ensure you honor that assertion that the field will not be null.

Comment: Another example of NRT being really annoying in blazor is the `[Inject]` attribute which has all of the same problems.  At least with that annoyance, it's possible to provide constructor injection now (using some hacks with `IComponentActivator`) and [will be officially supported in .NET 7](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18088#issuecomment-1039500017).

Comment: `= default!` has been working well for me for `[Inject]`, but for @ref items, i still get the warning `Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.`  if i try `private Modal addModal = default!;`

Comment: That is not my experience, Kyle.  Are you positive that that warning ("Cannot convert null") is actually pointing to that line?

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that nullable reference types does extensive control flow analysis.  Which, while impressive, can often lead to surprising results where just by treating a nullable reference as not null (_somewhere_ in the method) can change the nature of the errors displayed.

Answer (score 19):

Decorate with **[AllowNull]** - this will remove the annoying warning from razor. This works on VS 17.4.1 ... don't know about previous or future versions.

```
    [AllowNull]
    private Modal addModal;
```

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I use a separate file to keep my code behind.  I came across the same issue.  `private MudDropContainer<DropItem> container = default!;` works specifically on the code behind file, but I would still get the warning on the razor page when using the `@ref="@container"`.

Ultimately I ended up doing this `private MudDropContainer<DropItem>? container = default!;` which did work.  But I suspect the issue is more related to the razor designer and may be something that is resolved in a later release.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell the compiler that you know the object will not be null as follows...

```cs
private Model addModel = null!;
```

That disables the warning.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. the markup still shows the warning

Comment: @DLeh Odd, works for me. Try using `new()` instead of `null!` and see if that helps. If not, then it may be something we can't work out without seeing code.

Comment: it's weird, even though i have it defined as non-nullable it still shows warning: `private SnackbarStack snackbar = new();` `<SnackbarStack @ref="snackbar" />` shows squiggles on the last few chars of the html, and then on the rest of the document below it. the `[AllowNull]` option works though

Comment: Does sound odd, but without seeing the code, it's impossible to say for sure what's happening. As long as you found a solution you're OK.

Answer (score 3):

Declare it as nullable:

```
private Model? addModel;
```