# "Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type" when using @ref in a Blazor component

Tags: c#, blazor

I understand the concept of non-nullable types, and try to use them whenever possible, but have hit a situation where I don't understand what to do.

If I create a Blazor component (content irrelevant and therefore not shown), and want to refer to it in code, I can add a private variable for it. Since I know that Blazor will assign it a value, I can tell the compiler not to worry that it is non-nullable, but I haven't set an initial value...

```cs
private MyComponent _myComponent = null!;
```

I can then use `@ref` in the markup, which will populate the variable with a reference to the component...

```xml
<MyComponent @ref="_myComponent" />
```

However, Visual Studio gives me a wavy green line under the last part of this line, and a warning "*Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type*".

I'm not sure how to get around this. I'm not even sure what the warning means, as I told the compiler that the variable won't be null.

Can anyone explain a) what I'm doing wrong here, and b) how I should be doing this? Thanks

Comment: And what happens if you replace `private MyComponent` with `private MyComponent?`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do @ref's in Blazor have to be nullable to avoid warnings if nullable reference types are turned on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72370553/do-refs-in-blazor-have-to-be-nullable-to-avoid-warnings-if-nullable-reference)

Comment: @gunr2171 Sorry, forgot to include that in my question. Yes, I can mark the variable as nullable, but then that gives warnings in my code, unless I use `_myComponent!.Whatever` which is extra syntax for no good reason. I know the variable won't be null, so why can't I mark it as such where it is defined?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74614672/1403794

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `= null!;`, which you (understandably) said you don't want to use, how about...

```cs
private MyComponent _myComponent = new();
```

This obviously only works if the constructor doesn't take any parameters. If it does, you'd have to add some dummy values for those. This isn't an issue, as the framework will overwrite your value with a reference to the actual form, and it does get around your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private CptVendor? _myComponent = null!;
```

Comment: Thanks, but if you look at my comment from the 17th Nov, you'll see why I don't want to do that